# How do I automatically implicitly create a instance of a class at program launch?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a Winsock wrapper library and I want to automatically call `WSAStartup` when the program runs and `WSACleanup` when the program exits. These two functions will be wrapped up in a class with constructor and destructor. The class will handle multiple instances etc.

The first thing I thought of is using `extern wrapper dummy` in the library so an instances is created before anything happens and the destructor should be called when the program exits (I think).

Would this work or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You can just make a global object or static member, which are both initialized before `main`. But beware of the [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof). You cannot have a global or static member's construction depend on another from another translation unit, directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a class to only do the initialization and deinitialization once and inherit from that class in your winsock classes.

This does [lazy initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) and avoids the risk of [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof).

Example:

```
#include <stdexcept>

class WSA {
    struct Cleaner { // a class to just call WSACleanup()
        ~Cleaner() { ::WSACleanup(); }
    };

    static bool in;
    static Cleaner cln; // a static instance of the Cleaner class to cleanup only once

    static bool init() {
        DWORD wVersionRequired = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
        WSADATA WSAData;
        int rv =::WSAStartup(wVersionRequired , &WSAData);
        if(rv) throw std::runtime_error("WSAStartup failed");
        return true;
    }
};

bool WSA::in = WSA::init(); // init() will only be executed once
WSA::Cleaner WSA::cln;
```

Example usage:

```
class Socket : WSA {
    //...
};
```

It stores one `bool` + one `Cleaner` instance in total for all instances of `WSA` so it won't be much overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a 'dummy' class, whose constructor and destructor execute, respectively, your program's start-up and shut-down code. Then just create a (possibly `static`) *global* instance of that class, which will force the constructor and destructor to be called on program start-up and exit.

Here's a short demonstration program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class InOut {
    public:
        InOut() {
            std::cout << "Program starting up..." << std::endl;
            // WSAStartup() call
        }
        ~InOut() {
            std::cout << "Program terminating..." << std::endl;
            // WSACleanup() call
        }
};

static InOut object;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "This is inside main!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, if you want to to use more than one such class object, or do anything that may involve inter-class dependencies, take note of the warning given in the comments about [static class initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof)!